# View controller is not autorotating when Action Sheet is presented

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a viewController that autorotates just fine, The problem is that is I have an Action Sheet opened, when I rotate the device the Action Sheet is not rotating.

Is there a way to make it autorotate.

Anyone's Help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIActionSheet autorotates automatically - its orientation is the same as the view's on which it is being shown.
So that if you have a controller which can be rotated to any orientation(implements the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return YES;
}
```

)
Then if you show your UIActionSheet in this controller's view, action sheet will be of the same orientation as the controller's view and will autorotate automatically.

But if you will somehow show this UIActionSheet in the window(main application window), which does not autorotate to landscape, than your controller will rotate to landscape and after clicking the button, your UIActionSheet won't be presented in landscape but in portrait as the main window.

Comment: Thanks very much.Its working fine when Im adding the action sheet to the controller but I got nother problem actually Im having a tabbar in my view and the actionsheet displays on the tababar.Iam having cancel button in the action sheet when I tap the cancel button in upper part its working and when I click into lower its not coz behind the lower part tabbar is there so its not working.can u gimme any idea for this?

Comment: I suppose that you show the UIActionSheet in the controller's view then. Try showing it from tabBar:
[sheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
This should help :)

Comment: I'm using the 3.1.2 SDK and my UIActionSheet is not being rotated, even though the view it is shown over is autorotated. I'm using the showInView: method and passing the viewcontroller's view as a parameter. If I open the actionsheet in portrait or landscape it works, but it will not rotate WHILE it is shown.

Comment: True. ActionSheet won't be rotated then. This is how the SDK works(see in the Mail application - view the mail, press the reply button and rotate the device to the landscape). I guess the view on which the UIActionSheet is being shown is not rotating to the landscape when the UIActionSheet is shown as well, cause is this manner the view is not at the top so that doesn't rotate - and the rotation of the UIActionSheet depends on the view in which it is shown.

Comment: @krasnyk: so in this last case, there isn't a solution, is it?